# Permutation matrix associated to a group action.

Tags: permutations, group-actions, permutation-cycles, permutation-matrices

In the following [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.08389.pdf) (Example 1.2) I don't understand how a group action is associated to a certain permutation matrix.

We consider the cyclic group $G = \mathbb{Z}_6$ and for $g \in G$ we define the action on the set $M = \{1,2,3, 4, 5, 6\}$ as $g \cdot m := g-m \, \text{mod 6}$. Then, for $g=\bar{2}$, the following permutation matrix is associated to the group action.

$$2_N = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

I don't know how such matrix is retrieved, it corresponds to the cycle $(13)(2)(46)(5)$ but I cannot see how it is related to how the group action is defined in this case.

Comment: Note that the rows are permutations of the identity matrix in the same way that the group action permutes the elements of $M$. So the second row is stabilized, the first and third are swapped, etc. This matrix will in turn permute other matrices of the same size so you can compose permutations with matrix multiplication.

Comment: I just have troubles understanding the group action then. Let's take $m=2$. Then $\bar{2} - \bar{2} \,\,mod\,3 = 0 \, \, mod \,3$. How does this mean that the second row stays unchanged? Also, taking $m=1$ we have $\bar{2} - \bar{1} \,\,mod\,3 = 1 \, \, mod \,3$, how does this mean that the first column is swapped with the third? I just cannot see that.

Comment: The rows and columns are indexed in the order 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, not in the order 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0.  So 2 - 0 = 2, 2 - 1 = 1 is fixed, 2 - 2 = 0 completes a two-cycle, etc.  (For the other cases, you will actually have to reduce mod 6.)